# When to use []byte or string in Go?

Tags: string, arrays, go

Frequently in writing Go applications, I find myself with the choice to use `[]byte` or `string`. Apart from the obvious mutability of `[]byte`, how do I decide which one to use?

I have several use cases for examples:

1. A function returns a new `[]byte`. Since the slice capacity is fixed, what reason is there to not return a string?
2. `[]byte` are not printed as nicely as `string` by default, so I often find myself casting to `string` for logging purposes. Should it always have been a `string`?
3. When prepending `[]byte`, a new underlying array is always created. If the data to prepend is constant, why should this not be a `string`?

Comment: This sounds like it depends on your use. If you plan to be doing string-y ops with them, then call it a `string`. If it's just opaque data being shuffled around, why not `[]byte`? It comes down to the use cases.

Comment: And if you need to process individual characters, instead of a stream of UTF-8 encoded bytes, then convert it to runes first (32 bit ints IIRC).

Comment: then there is also `[]rune`, which is the best to represent a mutable string of characters

Comment: The mutability really is the key difference between a string and a slice of bytes or runes.  There are many subtle nuances when dealing with slices if the original array is modified -- such as cases where a slice of that array was used as a key in a map, or stored elsewhere.  Try to avoid falling into the habit of thinking of slices as a fixed tuple -- they are really more like C pointers with length.

Comment: Go has a type named `rune`? My opinion of Google has gone up a bit.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

My advice would be to use string by default when you're working with text. But use []byte instead if one of the following conditions applies:

- The mutability of a []byte will significantly reduce the number of allocations needed.
- You are dealing with an API that uses []byte, and avoiding a conversion to string will simplify your code.

Comment: Shouldn't the case of whether we are dealing or not exclusively with ASCII characters be factored in? Cause if not, a `byte` cannot hold such a character and we need the `rune` to be used?

Comment: A `[]byte` can hold non-ASCII characters if they are encoded as bytes (for example. in UTF-8).

Comment: I assume in that case we may not have 1-1 char-byte mapping (`UTF-8` codepoints  may be represented from 1 to 4 `bytes`).

Comment: That's right. But that's the way it is with a `string` too.

Comment: I've often found the conversion to string is convenient because of missing scanning functions that don't work on byte arrays. But coverting to string is unnecessary copying.  When working with large files it's better not to convert to a string of possible.  It gives a massive performance boost

Answer (score 22):

I've gotten the sense that in Go, more than in any other non-ML style language, the type is used to convey meaning and intended use. So, the best way to figure out which type to use is to ask yourself what the data *is*.

A string represents text. Just text. The encoding is not something you have to worry about and all operations work on a character by character basis, regardless of that a 'character' actually is.

An array represents either binary data or a specific encoding of that data. `[]byte` means that the data is either just a byte stream or a stream of single byte characters. `[]int16` represents an integer stream or a stream of two byte characters.

Given that fact that pretty much everything that deals with bytes also has functions to deal with strings and vice versa, I would suggest that instead of asking what you need to do with the data, you ask what that data represents. And then optimize things once you figure out bottlenecks.

EDIT: [This post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/golang-nuts/84GCvDBhpbg) is where I got the rationale for using type conversion to break up the string.

Answer (score 10):

1. One difference is that the returned `[]byte` can be potentially
   reused to hold another/new data (w/o new memory allocation), while
   `string` cannot. Another one is that, in the gc implementation at
   least, `string` is a one word smaller entity than `[]byte`. Can be
   used to save some memory when there is a lot of such items live.
2. Casting a `[]byte` to `string` for logging is not necessary. Typical 'text' verbs, like `%s`, `%q` work for `string` and `[]byte` expressions
   equally. In the other direction the same holds for e.g. `%x` or `% 02x`.
3. Depends on why is the concatenation performed and if the result is ever
   to be again combined w/ something/somewhere else afterwards. If that's the case then `[]byte` may perform better.

Comment: FWIW, The `%v` specifier treats []byte as an array of integers, this is the default for non `-f` methods. Also what about functions that return slices, rather than taking them as arguments?

Comment: what do you mean by "string is a one word smaller entity than []byte" ?

Comment: It has been nearlly a year since @animaacija comment but i figure I'll answer it: as `string`s are inmutable, they are represented as a pointer and a length internally while `[]byte`s also require the capacity.

Answer (score 1):

> I find myself with the choice to use `[]byte` or `string`

Since the introduction of generics, you can sometimes avoid having to face that choice: If it isn't clear whether a function should accept a `string` parameter or a `byte` slice, you could instead make the function generic by introducing a type parameter constrained by the following type set:

```
type StringOrByteSlice interface {
    string | []byte
}
```

For example, consider you want to define the function `SendJson`, which accepts an `http.ResponseWriter` and a JSON string to be sent as the response's body. Should you define it as `SendJson(http.ResponseWriter, string)` or as `SendJson(http.ResponseWriter, []byte)`?

Well, you could define it so that it accepts both `string` and `[]byte`:

```
func SendJson[T StringOrByteSlice](w http.ResponseWriter, json T) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write([]byte(json))
}
```