# Advantages to JSON as []byte instead of string?

Tags: json, go

RFC 7159 says

> JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) is a text format for the
> serialization of structured data.

Go uses `[]byte` for JSON in its `Marshal`/`Unmarshal` signatures:

```
func Marshal(v interface{}) ([]byte, error)
func Unmarshal(data []byte, v interface{}) error
```

Is there any practical advantage to using `[]byte` over `string` here, or any Go convention that says which should be used?

I could not find any explanation at
https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/ or
https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go.

Comment: A string is a `[]byte` internally in Go, using the raw type has some efficiency advantages.

Comment: You read and write data to and from `[]byte` slices, so that is the type you have in nearly all cases. What would be the point of requiring that the data be converted to a `string`?

Comment: Similar question was asked a while ago:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826651/when-to-use-byte-or-string-in-go

Comment: Huh, I'm more in line JimB's comment than the accepted answer on that other question. There are a number of places where strings are the right fit (map keys, short strings for config etc. or readonly data), but (perhaps confusingly) it has more to do with how you're using the data than whether it's text or something else.

Comment: (I don't agree with the downvotes on the question--yes, it's based on an assumption about strings and text that's wrong as applied to Go, but it's a clear question and it might useful for folks to _find out_ about how strings and bytes work in Go.)

Comment: FWIW, nominating this for reopening for roughly the reason in my 2018 comment: the core question, "why is JSON stored in []byte", is can be answered based on Go's definitions and mechanics. Votes indicate some folks found the answer useful. The asker's incorrect assumption that text should always be a string in Go doesn't cancel that out.

Comment: Possibly of interest: [BSON - Binary JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON).

Answer (score 18):

Go does *not* go by "strings are for text, byte types are for other stuff" like some other languages (e.g. Python 3) do. ["In Go, a string is in effect a read-only slice of bytes."](https://blog.golang.org/strings) The `string` type has a few behaviors attached that are handy for dealing with UTF-8 text, but it'll hold whatever bytes you put in it. Text-handling stuff in the standard library is often written to work with `[]byte`s too, e.g. [package `bytes`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/) mirrors [package `strings`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/) and [`regexp`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/) deals in either.

Given that there's no rule about text/binary semantically belonging in one type or the other, the choice to use `[]byte` was probably made for practical reasons. Since strings are *read-only* slices of bytes, almost all operations changing strings have to copy bytes to a new string instead of modifying the existing one. (String slicing is a key exception; it just makes a new string header that can point into the old string's bytes.)

Copying string contents for each operation leads to a quadratic slowdown as the string length and number of copies both grow with input size. On top of the direct cost of the copies, allocating the space for them makes garbage collection happen more often. For those reasons, almost everything that builds up content via a lot of small operations in Go uses a `[]byte` internally. That includes Go's  JSON-marshalling code, and the [`strings.Builder`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Builder) class added in Go 1.10.

(For similar reasons, [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530023/what-is-the-cost-of-operation-on-a-string-in-java) and [C#](https://ericlippert.com/2013/06/24/string-concatenation-behind-the-scenes-part-two/) offer string-builder types as well and modern JavaScript VMs have clever tricks to defer copying bytes until after a long series of concat operations, such as [V8's cons strings](https://gist.github.com/mraleph/3397008) and [SpiderMonkey's ropes](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/999385a5e8c2d360cc37286882508075fc2078bd/js/src/vm/String.h#44).)

Because `[]byte`s are read-write and strings are read-only, *converting* one to the other also has to copy bytes. If MarshalJSON returned a `string`, that would require making another copy of the content (and the associated load on the GC). Also, if you're ultimately going to do I/O with this, `Write()` takes a byte slice, so for that you'd have to convert back, creating another copy. (To slightly mitigate that, some I/O types including `*os.File` support `WriteString()` as well. But not all do!)

So it makes more sense for `json.Encoder` to return the `[]byte` it built up internally; you can of course call `string(bytes)` on the result if you need a `string` and the copying isn't a problem.

A bit out of the original question's scope, but often the best performing option is just to stream the output directly to an `io.Writer` using a [`json.Encoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder). You *never* have to allocate the whole chunk of output at once, and it can make your code simpler as well since there's no temp variable and you can handle marshalling and I/O errors in one place.